# What kind of stabilizers can I use when making souffles, Japanese cheesecake or egg beaten products?

Tags: baking, substitutions, cake

I would like to know more about effective stabilizers for egg-based cakes and similar dishes. I've heard that some people use gelatine, but wouldn't that make the cake ( Japanese cheesecake) have a jelly texture? Are there other options if this is the case as I want to preserve the light, egg-y fluffiness of these dishes?

Comment: Japanese "rare cheesecake" (レアーチーズケーキ) isn't usually particularly gelatinous in my experience, but it also doesn't typically have eggs in it; it will typically have lemon though. The Japanese-style soufflé cheesecake, on the other hand, has eggs but uses foamed egg white (meringue) for structure instead of gelatin. I think the ratio of gelatin is relatively small compared to, for example, a "mousse cake".

Answer (score 2):

For non-culinary reasons, I would offer substitutions to gelatin;

- As for a powerful stabilizer akin to gelatin but that doesn't precisely gel (go to pectin for that), when you are heating the food I have found **agar** to be a pretty effective stabilizer in vegan quiche that rely on a silken tofu base.
  I have used it to stabilize cheesecakes, pudding pies, and puree
  based pies and been pleased each time.
- As for a middling stabilizer/thickener, i.e. if you don't want to
  veer nearer to the gelatin edge, you can try **tapioca flour**; per
  Isa Chandra Moskovitz, "[sometimes tapioca flour can be used]
  interchangeably with corn-starch in recipes, but we feel it does have
  a different kind of cooked texture (thicker, gooier)."[[VPITS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738212741)
  p.7]